# Setting the values to the JavaScript Global variables setting in SonarQube

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube-scan

I have an ASP.NET MVC application and I added the `sonar-project.properties` file to the same folder as the solution file. I just wanted to add a global variable to the `sonar.javascript.globals` setting, but it doesn't seem have an impact. I don't have access to the machine where SonarQube runs,  I am just able to see the violations in a SonarQube website. I just have the 3 settings in the `sonar-project.properties`

```
sonar.projectKey= <key>
sonar.projectName= <name>

sonar.javascript.globals= <global_variable_name>
```

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by marking the JavaScript global variable to be a member of the window object. SonarQube now no longer complains the variable is undeclared.
For e.g. `window.<variable>`